# error when tried to read file csv using google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

[error while read file csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVO68.png)

confuse error while try to read file csv. i try to analyze data using google colab. when i try to read file csv this happened (attached). Anyone can help me about this problem? thank you for your kindness

Comment: What's the error? I can't find any error in the given image.